# how to use angularJS with appended elements

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, appendchild

Basically, i have a structure like this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlXUZ.png)

[image]

Every cell of last column needs to have this formula:

```
value[i][2] = value[i-1][2] + value[i][0] - value[i][1]
```

I'm actually having 2 problems. The first one comes when i just try to program the first row of the table. What's wrong with this extremely simple thing?

```
angular.module('calc', [])
    .controller('cont', function($scope) {
        $scope.addNumbers = function() {
            var c = aCom[30][5];
            var a = parseFloat($scope.entrata1);
            var b = parseFloat($scope.uscita1);
            return  c+a-b;
        }
});
```

considering `entrata1` and `uscita1` as they are `value[0][0]` and `value[0][1]`.

But most important, how can I extend the formula to all other rows? Consider that every row except the first one is created dinamically with an `appendChild()`function to the `body`, do i have to use at every appended item the function `setAttribute("ng-model","entrata")`?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest forget appendchild. Use ng-repeat and add rows adding to the scope
like this

```js
angular.module('plunker', []).controller('tableCtrl', function($scope,$filter) {
    $scope.rows = [{'a': 0,'u': 300},{'a': 0,'u': 150},{'a': 200,'u': 0},{'a': 0,'u': 300}];
    $scope.rowscalc = function(val){
     var total=0;
     angular.forEach($scope.rows, function(values, key){
      if(key<=val) total += values.u-values.a;});
     return total;
    };
    $scope.addRowM = function(){
     $scope.rows.push({'a': 0, 'u': 0});
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="tableCtrl">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td class="dthead">A</td>
                <td class="dthead">U</td>
                <td class="dthead">Total</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
                <td><input type="number" ng-model="row.a"/></td>
                <td><input type="number" ng-model="row.u"/></td>
                <td>{{rowscalc($index)}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <button ng-click="addRowM()">Add Row</button>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

you can check in [plunker](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/GvdriAWbZfLvs7kP?preview)